# PyMongo: unable to list all the databases

Tags: python, database, mongodb, nosql, pymongo

I have setup a Mongod server on one host
and am accessing that remotely from another host

Connecting to Mongod server via this code

```
import pymongo

Connection_String = "mongodb://mongohost:27017"
session = pymongo.MongoClient(Connection_String)
db = session.list_database_names()
print(db)
```

This is printing only 3 databases

**
['admin', 'config', 'local']
**

whereas If i query from mongo shell on the mongohost, it is showing all the databases

```
> show dbs
admin     0.000GB
config    0.000GB
local     0.000GB
panauto   0.000GB
marcopolo 0.000GB
```

Comment: I'd be fairly sure you're looking at two different databases.

Comment: got it solved, apparently one has to add some records to let the remote hosts properly list the documents

Answer (score 1):

Add atleast 1 document(.i.e., record) in the collection(i.e., table) under the database, so that the database can be actually created and displayed.

#Below is an example- to explain the same:

import pymongo

myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")

#create database "Company"

mydb = myclient["Company"]

#create collection "Employees"

mycol = mydb["Employees"]

#Define a document

Emp = { "EmpID": "1", "Name": "John" ,"Designation":"Manager"}

#insert document in collection "Employees"

mycol.insert_one(Emp)

#display the documents inside collection.

for x in mycol.find():
print(x)

#display the list of databases

print(myclient.list_database_names())

Comment: yes, this had solved my query, adding some documents led to proper listing of all records both at remote host as well as the mongo host itself

Answer (score 0):

Show me your the version of pymongo，I think your version was low，Because the database numbers are all right in the my computer.

The version of pymongo in the my computer：

```sh
>>> import pymongo
>>> pymongo.__version__
'3.12.0'
```

Use pymongo to get the list of databases：

```py
Connection_String = "mongodb://192.168.8.238:27017"
session = pymongo.MongoClient(Connection_String)
db = session.list_database_names()
print(db)
```

Result：

```sh
['admin', 'config', 'flog', 'local', 'opslog', 'slog', 'testlog']
```

In the Mongo Shell，I run "show dbs" command：

```sh
> show dbs
admin    0.000GB
config   0.001GB
flog     0.072GB
local    0.000GB
opslog   1.820GB
slog     0.000GB
testlog  3.771GB
```

So，Please update your Pymongo version。

Comment: Thanks for reverting  3.12.0 is the pymongo version i get , if i run the script from the mongodb server, then it shows all dbs successfully

Comment: You need write some datas to these collections in  the MongoDB. Perhaps，You will can see these collections when run python scripts， Because Collection of the MongoDB was created, When you write some datas to it.